# I have two csv's .. need to compare and print result if different in python

Tags: python, csv, compare

I have two csv's having results of same files. like:

```
File   Result
a.pdf, malicious
b.pdf, non-malicious  
c.pdf  malicious
```

and the second csv but having results of same file, like:

```
File   Result
a.pdf  non-malicious
b.pdf  malicious
c.pdf  non-malicious
```

I need to compare both printout the file name having different result... but in python..

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: i just google some codes but they are not working accurately

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code-writing or tutorial service.

Comment: with open(filename1, 'rb') as f1, open(filename2, 'rb') as f2

  rdr1 = CsvReader(f1)
  rdr2 = CsvReader(f2)

  for file1_line in rdr1:

     file2_line = rdr2.next()

     # Perform your comparison between file1_line and file2_line here
     # and print differences, or accumulate only the differences in a 
     # results list.

Answer (score 1):

Use csv module in python to read in the files.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

csv.DictReader is a good choice. You'll get two dictionaries, which you can iterate and compare by keys.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
    import csv
    with open('A.csv', newline='') as fileA:
        with open('B.csv',newline='') as fileB:
            readA = csv.DictReader(fileA)
            readB = csv.DictReader(fileB)
            fields = ['File','Result']
            ListDiff = []
            for rowA in readA:
                for rowB in readB:
                    if rowA[fields[0]] == rowB[fields[0]] and rowA[fields[1]] != rowB[fields[1]]:
                        ListDiff.append(rowA[fields[0]])
                        break
    print(ListDiff)
```